# Rails belongs_to with conditions on originating table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, cancan, belongs-to

I have a `Transaction` model where `from_owner` is polymorphic, because the transaction could come from several other models.

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :from_owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

I am trying to set up a specific `belongs_to` for when `from_owner_type` is a particular value:

```
belongs_to :from_person,
           conditions: ['from_owner_type = ?', Person.name],
           class_name: Person,
           foreign_key: 'from_owner_id'
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the `conditions` seem to be for `Person` and not `Transaction`. So I get the following SQL error trying to call `from_person` on a `Transaction`:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: from_owner_type: SELECT  "people".* FROM "people"  WHERE "people"."id" = 1 AND (from_owner_type = 'Person') LIMIT 1

What I want is for `from_person` on a `Transaction` to return `nil` if the `Transaction` `from_owner_type` is not `Person`, and otherwise return the related `Person`. I could set up a custom `from_person` method that does this, but I thought it might be possible as a `belongs_to`. I'm wanting to use this with CanCan conditions. I'm using Rails 3.

Comment: Do you just want this as a separate method to access the owner (if it's a `Person`), rather than this actually being a separate association? In that case it seems like a custom method would be a better option than trying to bend `belongs_to` to do something other than what it was intended for. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use a custom method?

Comment: I was hoping to, in CanCan, define an ability like `can :read, Transaction, from_person: {profile_id: profile.id}` which I think requires a relationship, not just a method. I think I'll have to do my definitions differently anyway, using a scope and a block, so this question may just be best answered by "define an instance method".

Comment: When setting a hash of conditions in CanCan, you need to use database columns ([see the CanCan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions)), so I suspect your approach may not work anyways. Can you not just add the check on the class name to part of the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it seems that the aim of this is to be able to set up a CanCan rule that allows a user to `:read` any `Transactions` that they are the owner of, correct? You should be able to do that with the following rule:

```
can :read, Transaction, from_owner_id: profile.id, from_owner_type: Person.name
```

and which should mean you don't need to bother messing anything with your `Transaction` model at all. (I haven't tested this, but the theory should be right, even if the syntax isn't quite there. For example, I'm not exactly sure where you `profile.id` comes from.)

Comment: Nah, there's another layer of indirection: `from_owner_id` won't be for a `Profile`, but a `Person`. So I need `from_owner: {profile_id: @profile.id}`. I need to go from `Transaction` => `Person` to access `profile_id` on `Person`.

Comment: Does it not work to combine that with the `from_owner_type` condition though? ie. `can :read, Transaction, from_owner_type: Person.name, from_owner: { profile_id: @profile.id }`? It may not, just guessing as I haven't used CanCan with a polymorphic association myself :)